# Can I recover the uncommited code from git pull -f?

Tags: git

I have some uncommited code there.

Today, a developer use `git pull -f` cover them.

As the question say, what can I do to recover the uncommited code.

Comment: ```I have some uncommited code there.``` > where? in your local computer? in shared development server? in remote git (e.g. github)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, each developer has their own local repository workspace, where they can do any pull they want without affecting your own local copy.

A `git pull -f` would only be an issue in a shared local repository, where multiple users log on and modify the same working tree.

If that was the case, and the files were not even added to the git cache (no `git add`), you would need to fallback to your IDE [local history feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) , to retrieve those files.